# How to resolve 'Unknown data property commerce_product' when adding a product in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm wondering if someone can help: I'm trying to add Drupal Commerce into an existing Drupal site, so I've followed the steps [in this video about this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iILniz-Kobk) and managed to install all modules without problems.

The issue I'm having is when I view a product I've added. Please note that I've added the product type. I can also add the node, but every time I try to view it I get this error (in the reports/error):

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property
>   commerce_product. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line
>   336 of
>   /my/local/server/php/mysite/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

I did follow all the steps in the tutorial. When I tried to view the product like in the video I get the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen that, but the problem is that the module referred in the answer is not longer maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an answer to "this" question might be similar to what I suggested in [How to add Drupal Commerce to an existing Drupal site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/156994), which originally was rather a request for manuals/docu about this topic. It has a comment (from the OPer) like this (bold markup added here now):

> ... After your post I've **uninstalled** all modules and **installed again** and **still had the errors**, however this time when I **run Commerce Repair** the fields were fixed **and everything worked**.

With that it appears to me that "this" question "has an answer" now also.

Ps: The "[Commerce Repair](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_repair)" module is "looking for a new maintainer", and used in over 1.000 sites. To me it appears as the best possible alternative to consider, which is not the same as "the module is no longer maintained" I believe (as I read in a comment to the question here).